# Gradle - исключить пакет из зависимости

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, dependency-injection

Необходимо подключить Rhino (интерпретатор JavaScript) к приложению на Android. Используется Gradle, зависимость добавляется без проблем:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7.2"
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что Rhino содержит пакет "tools" (org.mozilla.javascript.tools), в котором используются классы javax.swing, отсутствующие на Android, из-за чего ProGuard ругается и не позволяет собрать приложение ("Can't find common super class..." для класса, который использует javax.swing.JInternalFrame и находится в ненужном package "tools").

Возможно ли как-то исключить этот пакет из зависимости? Сделать так, чтобы он просто игнорировался во время сборки и не попал в результирующее приложение.

[image: Структура зависимости Rhino, выделен пакет tools, который нужно игнорировать]

Такой же вопрос был задан на форуме Gradle, но ответов не было: [Exclude package from dependency/runtime repackage dependency](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exclude-package-from-dependency-runtime-repackage-dependency/18785)

В поисках решения пробовал варианты:

```
compile ("org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7.2") {
    exclude group: 'org.mozilla.javascript.tools'
}
```

и

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'org/mozilla/javascript/tools/**'
        }
    }
}
```

, но безрезультатно.

Answer (score 1):

Надо либо искать сборку без этого пакета, либо самому ее сделать, скачав исходники.

Либо контрибутить сюда: https://github.com/F43nd1r/rhino-android

Comment: Другими словами, средствами Gradle это точно невозможно сделать?

Comment: Может и есть какой плагин, который перепакует dependency, вырезав пакет. Но посоветовать ничего конкретного не могу.